# SHA-256 implementation in Python

Tags: python, sha256

I'm looking for a Python implementation of the SHA-256 hash function. I want to use it to get a better understanding of how the SHA-256 function works, and I think Python is the ideal language for this. Pseudo-code has the limitation that I can't run/test it, to see what my modifications of the code do to the output.

Comment: However, for "production" use, it's (nearly) always better to use the library version of crypto code.

  from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

Comment: @MikeW, Is Pycrytodome proven tool? Is there other alternative?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

PyPy's source contains a pure-python implementation of SHA-256 [here](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/blob/branch/default/lib_pypy/_sha256.py). Poking around in that directory, you'll probably also find pure-python implementations of other standard hashes.

Answer (score 7):

```
initial_hash_values=[
'6a09e667','bb67ae85','3c6ef372','a54ff53a',
'510e527f','9b05688c','1f83d9ab','5be0cd19'
]

sha_256_constants=[
'428a2f98','71374491','b5c0fbcf','e9b5dba5',
'3956c25b','59f111f1','923f82a4','ab1c5ed5',
'd807aa98','12835b01','243185be','550c7dc3',
'72be5d74','80deb1fe','9bdc06a7','c19bf174',
'e49b69c1','efbe4786','0fc19dc6','240ca1cc',
'2de92c6f','4a7484aa','5cb0a9dc','76f988da',
'983e5152','a831c66d','b00327c8','bf597fc7',
'c6e00bf3','d5a79147','06ca6351','14292967',
'27b70a85','2e1b2138','4d2c6dfc','53380d13',
'650a7354','766a0abb','81c2c92e','92722c85',
'a2bfe8a1','a81a664b','c24b8b70','c76c51a3',
'd192e819','d6990624','f40e3585','106aa070',
'19a4c116','1e376c08','2748774c','34b0bcb5',
'391c0cb3','4ed8aa4a','5b9cca4f','682e6ff3',
'748f82ee','78a5636f','84c87814','8cc70208',
'90befffa','a4506ceb','bef9a3f7','c67178f2'
]

def bin_return(dec):
    return(str(format(dec,'b')))

def bin_8bit(dec):
    return(str(format(dec,'08b')))

def bin_32bit(dec):
    return(str(format(dec,'032b')))

def bin_64bit(dec):
    return(str(format(dec,'064b')))

def hex_return(dec):
    return(str(format(dec,'x')))

def dec_return_bin(bin_string):
    return(int(bin_string,2))

def dec_return_hex(hex_string):
    return(int(hex_string,16))

def L_P(SET,n):
    to_return=[]
    j=0
    k=n
    while k<len(SET)+1:
        to_return.append(SET[j:k])
        j=k
        k+=n 
    return(to_return)

def s_l(bit_string):
    bit_list=[]
    for i in range(len(bit_string)):
        bit_list.append(bit_string[i])
    return(bit_list)

def l_s(bit_list):
    bit_string=''
    for i in range(len(bit_list)):
        bit_string+=bit_list[i]
    return(bit_string)

def rotate_right(bit_string,n):
    bit_list = s_l(bit_string)
    count=0
    while count <= n-1:
        list_main=list(bit_list)
        var_0=list_main.pop(-1)
        list_main=list([var_0]+list_main)
        bit_list=list(list_main)
        count+=1
    return(l_s(list_main))

def shift_right(bit_string,n):
    bit_list=s_l(bit_string)
    count=0
    while count <= n-1:
        bit_list.pop(-1)
        count+=1
    front_append=['0']*n
    return(l_s(front_append+bit_list))

def mod_32_addition(input_set):
    value=0
    for i in range(len(input_set)):
        value+=input_set[i]
    mod_32 = 4294967296
    return(value%mod_32)

def xor_2str(bit_string_1,bit_string_2):
    xor_list=[]
    for i in range(len(bit_string_1)):
        if bit_string_1[i]=='0' and bit_string_2[i]=='0':
            xor_list.append('0')
        if bit_string_1[i]=='1' and bit_string_2[i]=='1':
            xor_list.append('0')
        if bit_string_1[i]=='0' and bit_string_2[i]=='1':
            xor_list.append('1')
        if bit_string_1[i]=='1' and bit_string_2[i]=='0':
            xor_list.append('1')
    return(l_s(xor_list))

def and_2str(bit_string_1,bit_string_2):
    and_list=[]
    for i in range(len(bit_string_1)):
        if bit_string_1[i]=='1' and bit_string_2[i]=='1':
            and_list.append('1')
        else:
            and_list.append('0')
            
    return(l_s(and_list))

def or_2str(bit_string_1,bit_string_2):
    or_list=[]
    for i in range(len(bit_string_1)):
        if bit_string_1[i]=='0' and bit_string_2[i]=='0':
            or_list.append('0')
        else:
            or_list.append('1')
    return(l_s(or_list))

def not_str(bit_string):
    not_list=[]
    for i in range(len(bit_string)):
        if bit_string[i]=='0':
            not_list.append('1')
        else:
            not_list.append('0')
    return(l_s(not_list))

'''
SHA-256 Specific Functions:
'''

def Ch(x,y,z):
    return(xor_2str(and_2str(x,y),and_2str(not_str(x),z)))

def Maj(x,y,z):
    return(xor_2str(xor_2str(and_2str(x,y),and_2str(x,z)),and_2str(y,z)))

def e_0(x):
    return(xor_2str(xor_2str(rotate_right(x,2),rotate_right(x,13)),rotate_right(x,22)))

def e_1(x):
    return(xor_2str(xor_2str(rotate_right(x,6),rotate_right(x,11)),rotate_right(x,25)))

def s_0(x):
    return(xor_2str(xor_2str(rotate_right(x,7),rotate_right(x,18)),shift_right(x,3)))

def s_1(x):
    return(xor_2str(xor_2str(rotate_right(x,17),rotate_right(x,19)),shift_right(x,10)))

def message_pad(bit_list):
    pad_one = bit_list + '1'
    pad_len = len(pad_one)
    k=0
    while ((pad_len+k)-448)%512 != 0:
        k+=1
    back_append_0 = '0'*k
    back_append_1 = bin_64bit(len(bit_list))
    return(pad_one+back_append_0+back_append_1)
    
def message_bit_return(string_input):
    bit_list=[]
    for i in range(len(string_input)):
        bit_list.append(bin_8bit(ord(string_input[i])))
    return(l_s(bit_list))

def message_pre_pro(input_string):
    bit_main = message_bit_return(input_string)
    return(message_pad(bit_main))

def message_parsing(input_string):
    return(L_P(message_pre_pro(input_string),32))

def message_schedule(index,w_t):
    new_word = bin_32bit(mod_32_addition([int(s_1(w_t[index-2]),2),int(w_t[index-7],2),int(s_0(w_t[index-15]),2),int(w_t[index-16],2)]))
    return(new_word)

'''
This example of SHA_256 works for an input string <56 characters.
'''

def sha_256(input_string):
    assert len(input_string) < 56, "This example of SHA_256 works for an input string <56 characters."
    w_t=message_parsing(input_string)
    a=bin_32bit(dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[0]))
    b=bin_32bit(dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[1]))
    c=bin_32bit(dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[2]))
    d=bin_32bit(dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[3]))
    e=bin_32bit(dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[4]))
    f=bin_32bit(dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[5]))
    g=bin_32bit(dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[6]))
    h=bin_32bit(dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[7]))
    for i in range(0,64):
        if i <= 15: 
            t_1=mod_32_addition([int(h,2),int(e_1(e),2),int(Ch(e,f,g),2),int(sha_256_constants[i],16),int(w_t[i],2)])
            t_2=mod_32_addition([int(e_0(a),2),int(Maj(a,b,c),2)])
            h=g
            g=f
            f=e
            e=mod_32_addition([int(d,2),t_1])
            d=c
            c=b
            b=a 
            a=mod_32_addition([t_1,t_2])
            a=bin_32bit(a)
            e=bin_32bit(e)
        if i > 15:
            w_t.append(message_schedule(i,w_t))
            t_1=mod_32_addition([int(h,2),int(e_1(e),2),int(Ch(e,f,g),2),int(sha_256_constants[i],16),int(w_t[i],2)])
            t_2=mod_32_addition([int(e_0(a),2),int(Maj(a,b,c),2)])
            h=g
            g=f
            f=e
            e=mod_32_addition([int(d,2),t_1])
            d=c
            c=b
            b=a 
            a=mod_32_addition([t_1,t_2])
            a=bin_32bit(a)
            e=bin_32bit(e)
    hash_0 = mod_32_addition([dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[0]),int(a,2)])
    hash_1 = mod_32_addition([dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[1]),int(b,2)])
    hash_2 = mod_32_addition([dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[2]),int(c,2)])
    hash_3 = mod_32_addition([dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[3]),int(d,2)])
    hash_4 = mod_32_addition([dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[4]),int(e,2)])
    hash_5 = mod_32_addition([dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[5]),int(f,2)])
    hash_6 = mod_32_addition([dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[6]),int(g,2)])
    hash_7 = mod_32_addition([dec_return_hex(initial_hash_values[7]),int(h,2)])
    final_hash = (hex_return(hash_0),
                  hex_return(hash_1),
                  hex_return(hash_2),
                  hex_return(hash_3),
                  hex_return(hash_4),
                  hex_return(hash_5),
                  hex_return(hash_6),
                  hex_return(hash_7))
    return(final_hash)
```

Comment: That code looks like it has some license attached that would prevent you from posting it here without attribution.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I wrote the script. What is it about the code that makes you think that? The magic happens in int() and format()

Comment: @MattTimmermans You should see my SHA-3 answers then! Exact same style!

Comment: Is this tested? I got a different result when calling your `print(str(sha_256("hi")))` than when I ran `echo "hi" | sha256sum`

Comment: I'm late to the party, but the algorithm is not 100% correct. Sometimes it outputs strings where the size is 1 or 2 smaller than what it should be (62 or 63 instead of 64). I compare them with the hashlib output, and everything matches up perfectly, except that, for some reason one or two 0s are missing in the output (examples of 2 missing are "B" and "s"). I'm guessing this is because of some bug with the padding?

Comment: There is something wrong with the padding as inputting a string of 60 to 64 letters appears to output a completely different hash and sometimes there are random zeros in the hash which indicates that there is more than just padding that is wrong.

Comment: After doing a lot of debugging and comparing the code to that of the pseudocode on Wiki, I found a few issues the padding formula works but does not match the Wiki's formula. It does not do multiple chunks which is why it says that it works with an input_string < 56 characters. The main issue however is hex_return which does not format the number correctly which is why there are missing 00's and whatnot.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it and summited an edit with the new code. I hoped I helped! (:

Comment: This code is not fixed yet! This won't work if the message is greater than 448 bits. Try print(str(sha_256("hello world hello world hello world hello world hello wo"))). The correct value should be `5e1440c967b41e15a9c816b6f8c93195deaaceebc3b7a50293c61dfa7725f221` . To fix this 512 chunks algorithm must be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago I was also studying SHA-256 and created pure-python class that implements this hash. If I remember correctly, mostly I've taken algorithm from Wikipedia [SHA-256 Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Pseudocode) and partially from some open-source projects.

Algorithm doesn't import any (even standard) modules. Of cause it is much slower than `hashlib`'s variant and only meant for studying.

If you just run the script it executes 1000 tests comparing `hashlib`'s and my variants. Only testing function imports some modules, algorithm's class itself doesn't need any modules. Interface is same as in hashlib's sha256 class. See `test()` function for examples of usage.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVZNc9s2EL37V6CHVmRtKwAIgKQnyfTk6aW9pDdV1QAgYDEWJY9IT2VPp3/dXSwoiZRlN@FF0AL7dvftB/Dw1C036@zlxa5025IvS82lurkg8N235BOZ4TJ8dCd4obkviytY5yzLhShZWBtpqTfWh7UrjayMllcDvayUynJpwr4sPWPMo17JM19wLcJaG2alq0Z6VUFzraM9xotMGop6XGSskMYhnqQ2r2w21Mu5cbLKEbeglTPM49nSVJYqnYe1ZaXxDM4M9JwojSot2nDeOJEXKqyph9OVVdE2tZpZO9TjlSu5VRi/0LkohNbomzVUgyLypYC4otJDvbLInGSSY/xFxqxSFfJJacZzi3EbL8vc23yoZ5Wj1Pgs7FdS5yUTGBNVVqtMov9M8JKXaqTHc5NTXUiMwzHDWYY2RAXeVx79lFkGlLERn0pSnWdSxDiUptpgLgtmuS155JbnnNtilD/NjXeFZjE@ppUSqGe5MAW4gutcWcn0yF7FALRgJcanypIqjra9oC6T0X8GidQUMAZ6rNTCMoZ5Yi4DZIrxcUhJnguMLxOGGmtO6pNZag3yKVxVaC1i/kxprRaYV1Vwp7wf15kooH4dxp8XWqos1kAhbJEXLNaftTnl4Mcw79Q47z3a0EJC2hzyAtJSZz7Wp8pZXnge9eYX@LM87UjIRemUQg1jVK5dZCeDEvFZHitLCu9lNqo8yaiTPPexK6hURYHsMF9kValjpxpHLaRi5MFvGQcX6O62/6K0cp4sFvW67haLpHUrwG3g2O@btUtvDmbDxrRZuXVAGEvNowehmUzG4nsQxkU7u5mP95b7veXrPV8HG7d61brDRu3Bp7ol602Hjh39Oqg9PlS6c0mTxqh@aTvd1bZxMCGrQ5wPukpCEIPAmqoGcxjZT4H828MOiO664CmqkI8fSZZOu83CPHWuTaA4J6a@m6SH8wAe@ZGSXCNucBt@PhKpiIN4CGNl3DoobV33uF0De3/CtJuQS1xRWP28x7vsHXkvru1mm@yuyNMgrh44SXbk82fYIf8QWEIQCVTBNQjSFAKOV8YUKuM9@EZ/Rfgr8nzGwg5wAP@vuHrG1ROu3sO0y2@CTP7dpQMs1Nw0D1vXtn2x2oH@36HF6BzIU@IonFFyQ5iah8163U39dtP0WbSzGvZqIFnM9wklfrMFEZThVq/vXAKjDjKQ2PSKiLRvpfCdHAujS4n0pDTpvtJDiv4Ga9eESTBF8hDeuR1WYOAHSUgfVN4Ylr2GJTwon4ONO@UAFiQBltExLGwGkva2gbHLEMEliYIc/7OQD7RwqJrwwUCEyQODCG5BGKqQmLsrcuzzN2n7H8oAlo9CAgHLTiWcjwPpwqBDz@Pcgvrt/XuPR3BbjZBBwNiphMsTWwFjiczs7UFt9xSke9F9oBaJHFQQXgugfTeS3IHEjyRhvrqRxIU0VQDYjdMxPFPBGTuS2DCnRxIDEj2S6IDchVA6fj7TmMArEgdOSKRbPzZuG6bvc/2QxHxfkdn5ipin6Znpvewrbwd2n16bDW3fD/j@hhqA7C@HcDEQ8C00a5OST3BRjS3F6TIo2bZ12w4vlf3NAzPgV90uiV5tna6eCIj0qn52FdHrili9xtPG9d5UP0wuzlyRl596J463zL7OwmV5SZo326EfNuD/hw9nxglW137@NTMlYNSFCYaLJMwxls7Ti3MXdDPrga9J0q9@RAvzI8dVfefaDjkeEzzk6O3LF9fhjj1QkaavD0cj8ckw/bqp18nueK2K0RTeBWL6Arkp5mfA4mvhj@2jO71EBraOAS7d7nyMnQ6tMKGMZ0KqvIB3lAWFySnq3mU4PzNhhorQ1vFfeD/cztFxc3C8NwdEXAQHOvwT7dbNw2YbeLUA3kJvQOWtaugZKIVq01wcyiMoHUtEUjpwHIjXWFwIAkTeu3XPZYSZhp@oyWU@SEjozzC6otVpi0@BJOCl0yNPcOt9eWPntJF06DlwH2dt@m3un3fiaDQdNcrXI8yr4OAyO@mW76GG8fKkVvW@qjHu8dQ8v9XHosfsme@k7GELb5RkEuPHeoHp0z5aCy3vH1erpym8OS/q8Ghf68YtFgFislg0ul4vFpNIQSyzi5eX/wA)

```
class Sha256:
    ks = [
        0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,
        0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
        0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
        0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
        0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc,
        0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
        0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7,
        0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
        0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
        0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
        0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3,
        0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
        0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5,
        0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
        0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
        0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2,
    ]

    hs = [
        0x6a09e667, 0xbb67ae85, 0x3c6ef372, 0xa54ff53a,
        0x510e527f, 0x9b05688c, 0x1f83d9ab, 0x5be0cd19,
    ]

    M32 = 0xFFFFFFFF

    def __init__(self, m = None):
        self.mlen = 0
        self.buf = b''
        self.k = self.ks[:]
        self.h = self.hs[:]
        self.fin = False
        if m is not None:
            self.update(m)

    @staticmethod
    def pad(mlen):
        mdi = mlen & 0x3F
        length = (mlen << 3).to_bytes(8, 'big')
        padlen = 55 - mdi if mdi < 56 else 119 - mdi
        return b'\x80' + b'\x00' * padlen + length

    @staticmethod
    def ror(x, y):
        return ((x >> y) | (x << (32 - y))) & Sha256.M32

    @staticmethod
    def maj(x, y, z):
        return (x & y) ^ (x & z) ^ (y & z)

    @staticmethod
    def ch(x, y, z):
        return (x & y) ^ ((~x) & z)

    def compress(self, c):
        w = [0] * 64
        w[0 : 16] = [int.from_bytes(c[i : i + 4], 'big') for i in range(0, len(c), 4)]

        for i in range(16, 64):
            s0 = self.ror(w[i - 15],  7) ^ self.ror(w[i - 15], 18) ^ (w[i - 15] >>  3)
            s1 = self.ror(w[i -  2], 17) ^ self.ror(w[i -  2], 19) ^ (w[i -  2] >> 10)
            w[i] = (w[i - 16] + s0 + w[i - 7] + s1) & self.M32

        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = self.h

        for i in range(64):
            s0 = self.ror(a, 2) ^ self.ror(a, 13) ^ self.ror(a, 22)
            t2 = s0 + self.maj(a, b, c)
            s1 = self.ror(e, 6) ^ self.ror(e, 11) ^ self.ror(e, 25)
            t1 = h + s1 + self.ch(e, f, g) + self.k[i] + w[i]

            h = g
            g = f
            f = e
            e = (d + t1) & self.M32
            d = c
            c = b
            b = a
            a = (t1 + t2) & self.M32

        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(self.h, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h])):
            self.h[i] = (x + y) & self.M32

    def update(self, m):
        if m is None or len(m) == 0:
            return

        assert not self.fin, 'Hash already finalized and can not be updated!'

        self.mlen += len(m)
        m = self.buf + m

        for i in range(0, len(m) // 64):
            self.compress(m[64 * i : 64 * (i + 1)])

        self.buf = m[len(m) - (len(m) % 64):]

    def digest(self):
        if not self.fin:
            self.update(self.pad(self.mlen))
            self.digest = b''.join(x.to_bytes(4, 'big') for x in self.h[:8])
            self.fin = True
        return self.digest

    def hexdigest(self):
        tab = '0123456789abcdef'
        return ''.join(tab[b >> 4] + tab[b & 0xF] for b in self.digest())

def test():
    import secrets, hashlib, random
    for itest in range(500):
        data = secrets.token_bytes(random.randrange(257))
        a, b = hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest(), Sha256(data).hexdigest()
        assert a == b, (a, b)
    for itest in range(500):
        a, b = hashlib.sha256(), Sha256()
        for j in range(random.randrange(10)):
            data = secrets.token_bytes(random.randrange(129))
            a.update(data)
            b.update(data)
        a, b = a.hexdigest(), b.hexdigest()
        assert a == b, (a, b)
    print('Sha256 tested successfully.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want the hash value:

```
from hashlib import sha256
data = input('Enter plaintext data: ')
output = sha256(data.encode('utf-8'))
print(output)
```

Python's hashlib also has SHA-1, SHA-384, SHA-512, and MD5 hash functions.

Comment: Is Python built-in Hashlib widely used in industry? If not which tool is used among Pycrytpodome, Cryptogrphy or Pynacl?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my proposition with redis:

```
for i in range(len(rserver.keys())):
    mdp_hash = rserver.get(rserver.keys()[i])
    rserver.set(rserver.keys()[i], hashlib.sha256(mdp_hash.encode()).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score -2):

Translating http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#SHA-256_.28a_SHA-2_variant.29_pseudocode to Python should be straight forward.

Comment: This harder than it sounds because all the input / output conversion logic is not presented, and that is fairly non-trivial.