# how can i get the hash file for a set amount of digits?

Tags: python, hash

Honestly I don't know how to ask this but basically I want to make a script that gets me the sha256 hash of a random string. for example 0000000000 to 9999999999. At the end i want it to save it in a way such as string : hsa-256. I've tried searching for a way to do it in python to no avail.THIS ISN'T FOR PASSWORD HACKING PURPOSES. this is for a personal use.

Comment: excusatio non petita...

Comment: We believe u, if u were a hacker u prob know how to do it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pypy library which has a implementation of sha-256 [here](https://github.com/pypy/pypy/blob/master/lib_pypy/_sha256.py). 
You question seems to be repeat of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321694/sha-256-implementation-in-python).